# How to send Bitmap from server to client?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets

In my app I'm uploading a Bitmap to the server using MultiPartEntity.

**The code:**

```
public static boolean UploadFile(String stringUrl, byte[] bitmapArray) throws Exception { 
  String uploadUrl = stringUrl;
  HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);
  MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
  entity.addPart("image", new ByteArrayBody(bitmapArray, "image/png", "image"));
  postRequest.setEntity(entity);
  HttpResponse httpResponse;
  HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
  httpClient.getParams().setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",false);
  httpResponse = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    .
    .
}
```

And getting the Bitmap from the request and storing it in a blob.

**The Code:**

```
private void handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  try {
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
    FileItemStream imageItem = iter.next();
    InputStream imgStream = imageItem.openStream();
    Blob imageBlob = new Blob(IOUtils.toByteArray(imgStream));
    MyImage myImage = new MyImage(imageItem.getName(), imageBlob);
      .
      .
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {       
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I send it back to the client using the response? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Send a link back in response and initiate the download from the received link.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setContentType("image/png"); // fill proper image type
response.getOutputStream().write(IOUtils.toByteArray(imgStream));
```

more info at [Serving Dynamic Images with Google App Engine (Java)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/java/serving_dynamic_images)

Comment: trying reading it back in the client with 
  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());      byte[] input = (byte[]) in.readObject();
throws EOFException. any guess?

Comment: @Rami seek the stream to the start.

Comment: What does it mean? How can I do it?